# bleachbit get crushed previweing and cleaning these paths

Tags: 14.04, flash, bleachbit

Ubuntu 14.04LTS

```
/.config/vlc/vlc-qt-interface.conf
/firefox/permissions.sqlite
/flash-player
```

every time it never complete previewing or cleaning, each time in one of these files. even all programs are closed...

Comment: The files shown in the log are the paths that are done, so the path that is working on is not yet shown. For diagnosing the problem a good next step is previewing one path at a time, and what is the option that "gets crushed"?  Does "get crushed" means high CPU usage, high disk usage, non-responsive GUI, or something else? Which version of BleachBit?